# Change action bar background dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the background of my action bar dynamically. My code is:

```
ColorDrawable c1 = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ColorDrawable c2 = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
ColorDrawable[] colors = { c1, c2 };
TransitionDrawable tdraw = new TransitionDrawable(colors);
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(tdraw);
```

It works, but instead to use the color black, I'd like to do a transition to the default holo dark action bar. In this way indeed I can't see the classic blue line divider of Holo Dark. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the one to fade into the other on the same activity? If so, you'll probably be stuck with an open GL surface acting as action bar. Doing so is complicated, but you can start learning here:
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html